# Update View when property value changed inside setter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have checkbox in my view which has bound to the property in the viewmodel. When I check/uncheck the checkbox, there is one condition in setter of the property which updates the same property if the condition is true. But when the property gets updated corresponding view does not change.

Here is the code:
View:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HoldingPen,Mode="Twoway" ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public bool HoldingPen
{
  get{m_holdingPen;}
  set
  {
    m_hodingPen=value;
    onPropertyChanged("HoldingPen");
    OnHoldingPenCheckChanged();
  }

public void OnHoldingPenCheckChanged()
{
  if(HoldingPen && some other condition)
  {
    HoldingPen=false;  //Here view should be updated simultaneously 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you place the `OnHoldingPenCheckChanged` before the `onPropertyChanged` line? I think it might have to do with the timing of events

Comment: No ,it does not work.I tried all the permutations and combinations

Comment: Have you tried this? `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding HoldingPen,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: Yeah,tried that also.That is  not working

Comment: Changing the value of a property within the setter of the property just stinks.  Simply take your value, perform your check, determine the ultimate value of the property, set it once, then fire your changed event if the value actually changed.  Or, don't do any of that nonsense at all--use a separate property to indicate the state of HoldingPen + some other condition (can't tell if that's appropriate, but it smells less :/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a result of having two `onPropertyChanged` events fire, once with a value of `true` and one with a value of `false`

Typically for this kind of logic I prefer to use the PropertyChanged event instead of hiding the logic in property setters.

```
public class MyClass()
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        // attach property changed in constructor
        this.PropertyChanged += MyClass_PropertyChanged;
    }

    private void MyClass_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "HoldingPen")
            OnHoldingPenCheckChanged();
    }

    public bool HoldingPen
    {
        get{ m_holdingPen; }
        set
        {
            if (m_hodingPen == value)
                return; 

            m_hodingPen=value;
            onPropertyChanged("HoldingPen");
        }
    }

    public void OnHoldingPenCheckChanged()
    {
        if(HoldingPen && some other condition)
        {
            HoldingPen=false;  //Here view should be updated simultaneously 
        }
    }
}
```

This has the additional benefit of having any custom code to modify a value in one location, rather than going through each setter when looking for something.

Comment: I upvoted your answer because its good in general, but here I dont see reason why not check the condition inside the setter and avoid all the complexity

Comment: @DudiKeleti My main objection to putting logic in the setter is for debugging. I find it much easier to have one location where I can check to see if any special logic is being applied to any number of properties at once, rather than having to check each setter. By placing it all in the PropertyChanged event, I can keep all my property definitions very generic, and never have to go search through them to see if they do anything special

Comment: @VishalChavan I think something else may be wrong then, perhaps your DataContext or implementation of your PropertyChange notification. Is your code exactly like it is in your question? I have tested both with your original code and the PropertyChanged code I posted here, and both work fine.